# Docpad (on Mac) livereload does not recompile scss when a referenced scss file changes

Tags: docpad, node-sass

Repro steps are as follows:

I have a main.css.scss file that looks like this:

```
@import "defaults";
```

I have a _defaults.scss file that looks like this:

```
body { background: #FFF; }
```

When I first start the site, everything looks good. If I change main.css.scss, everything works as expected. But changes to _defaults.scss are not picked up unless I restart the server or touch main.css.scss

A workaround would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is true about docpad on any operating system though. Basically due to the fact that there is no logic in docpad for defining the relationship between all those `_*.scss` files and the one you want rebuilt.

At the moment, I'm leaning towards switching to Assemble#0.6.0/Verb/Template in my gulp tasks. But I still need to mockup a restful api server with my prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hacky, but this does fix the issue. In one terminal, I run the docpad server. In another terminal, I run this command:

```
fswatch-run src/documents/css/_* 'touch ./src/documents/css/main.css.scss'
```

What this does is touch the main scss file any time any of the imported scss files are touched.  This in turn causes docpad to pick up the change and recompile the scss. There's probably a much better way to do this, but this works at the moment.

It's too hacky for me to actually accept it as the answer, though.